# Php get Git Change Log of particular commit

Tags: php, git

I want to get list of files added, modified, deleted of particular Git Commit. But i could only get author, message, Date  and files list. but this does not show which file is added/modified/deleted.
Following is my code

```
 $cmd = 'git show --no-commit-id --name-only -r ' . $commit;
 exec($cmd, $files);
 debug($files); exit;
```

here **$commit** is commit id, which is i already fetch.

Comment: what about removing `--name-only` ?

Comment: by removing --name-only, return all dirty log

Answer (score 0):

`$cmd = 'git show --stat ' . $commit;`

Comment: this command does not tell me which file is deleted and which is added